# Return observable inside observable in canactivate guard of Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router, observable

So I have to do two things in my canActivate guard of the router. First I have to check if the user is authorized, I do this by calling OpenIdcSecutiry service, and then if the user is authorized I must check the users roles by calling another service that returns UserProfile including its roles. I know I can return an Observable and in fact if I just do:

```
return this.oidcSecurityService.getIsAuthorized();
```

It works, but obviously I does not check user roles. Right now I have this:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {

return this.oidcSecurityService.getIsAuthorized()
  .map(
    data => {
      if (data === false) {
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        return data;
      }
      if (data === true) {
        const roles = route.data['roles'] as Array<string>;
        if (roles) {
        this.profileService.getObservableUserProfileFromServer().map(userProfile => {
          const userRoles = userProfile.Roles;
          for (const role of roles) {
            if (userRoles.indexOf(role) > -1) {
              return true;
            }
          }
          return false;
        });
        }
        return data;
      }
    },
    error => {
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      return error;
    }
  );
```

**this.profileService.getObservableUserProfileFromServer()** is never called and I dont know how to check the user roles after I know the user is Authorized. How can I do this? Can I return the observable inside my observable?

EDIT1: I changed the code to this:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {

return this.oidcSecurityService.getIsAuthorized()
  .map(
    data => {
      if (data === false) {
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        return data;
      }
      if (data === true) {
        const roles = route.data['roles'] as Array<string>;
        if (roles) {
          return this.profileService.getObservableUserProfileFromServer().toPromise().then(userProfile => {
              const userRoles = userProfile.Roles;
              for (const role of roles) {
                if (userRoles.indexOf(role) > -1) {
                  return true;
                }
              }
              return false;
          }
            );
        }
        return data;
      }
    },
    error => {
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      return error;
    }
  );
```

// return this.oidcSecurityService.getIsAuthorized();

}

Now I can see how this.profileService.getObservableUserProfileFromServer is called and receive results from server, but the result is not evaluated in canActivate guard, it simply ignores the result and It says the Navigation was canceled.

EDIT FINAL:

@llai gave me the answer, two switchmaps must be used to chain several observables, final code here:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {

return this.oidcSecurityService.getIsAuthorized()
  .switchMap(
    data => {
      if (data === false) {
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        return Observable.of(false); // user not logged in, canActivate = false
      } else if (data === true) {
        const roles = route.data['roles'] as Array<string>;
        if (roles) {
          // return inner observable
          return this.profileService.getObservableUserProfileFromServer()
            .switchMap(userProfile => {
              const userRoles = userProfile.Roles;
              for (const role of roles) {
                if (userRoles.indexOf(role) > -1) {
                  // role found, canActivate = true
                  return Observable.of(true);
                }
              }
              // no matching role, canActivate = false
              return Observable.of(false);
            });
        } else {
          // no roles defined in route data, canActivate = false
          return Observable.of(true);
        }
      }
    });
```

}

Comment: Did you try to use switchMap instead of map and return it? 'return this.profileService.getObservableUserProfileFromServer().switchMap'

Comment: Just for testing I changed the code to:

if (roles) {
              return this.profileService.getObservableUserProfileFromServer().switchMap(userProfile => {
                return Observable.of(true);
              });

But Its not even calling the server of userProfile Service

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Christian mentioned in a comment, you should be using `switchMap` to chain your observables together.

In your first implementation you are not returning your inner observable therefore the router never subscribes to it, so it never gets called.

In your second implementation you are "subscribing" (convert to promise + then) to the observable within the map function, which makes the inner observable fire. However since the observable is not returned to the guard, the guard is not waiting for the inner observable to complete.

---

Instead you should chain the observables and return that chained sequence to the guard. This will allow the guard to subscribe to the sequence and wait for the proper response.

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {

    return this.oidcSecurityService.getIsAuthorized()
      .switchMap(
        data => {
          if (data === false) {
            this.router.navigate(['/login']);
            return Observable.of(false); // user not logged in, canActivate = false
          }else if (data === true) {
            const roles = route.data['roles'] as Array<string>;
            if (roles) {
              // return inner observable
              return this.profileService.getObservableUserProfileFromServer()
                .map(userProfile => {
                  const userRoles = userProfile.Roles;
                  for (const role of roles) {
                    if (userRoles.indexOf(role) > -1) {
                      // role found, canActivate = true
                      return true;
                    }
                  }
                  // no matching role, canActivate = false
                  return false;
                });
            }else{
              // no roles defined in route data, canActivate = false
              return Observable.of(false)
            }
          }
        }
      }
    );

}
```

Comment: I have tryed this and compiler is giving me the next error:

**The type argument for type parameter 'I' cannot be inferred from the usage. Consider specifying the type arg
uments explicitly.
  Type argument candidate 'boolean' is not a valid type argument because it is not a supertype of candidate 'Observable<boolean>'.**

Comment: @pablito what line are you getting that error? Make sure you are always returning an observable with a boolean within your switchMap. Also specify that the canActivate guard should expect `Observable<boolean>`

Comment: In this line:

return this.oidcSecurityService.getIsAuthorized().switchMap(

Comment: @pablito I've updated my answer. Try removing your second input to switch Map `err => {...}` The second input of switchMap is actually a result selector (https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html) which essentially can manipulate the output of the switchMap. We don't need that here

Comment: I have updated the code deleting the err => and now it says:

**The type argument for type parameter 'R' cannot be inferred from the usage. Consider specifying the type arg
uments explicitly.
  Type argument candidate 'boolean' is not a valid type argument because it is not a supertype of candidate 'Observable<boolean>'.** (Same line, the first one)

Comment: @pablito Ah ok I see, I was returning an observable within the map method. I've updated my answer to return just a boolean within map. But you are right you could also use a second switchMap. I would use the single switch map since you are doing a basic transform to return a boolean (after your second observable). I think this approach is more clear.

Comment: you are right, using second map is also correct, but boolean must be returned. Finally I'm using first a switchmap and then a map returning booleans. Thank you so much!

Comment: @pablito glad I could help!